# Error while using two times async within the EventHandler (BLoC)

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, bloc

I finished a tutorial from a YouTuber today regarding TDD and Clean Architecture with Flutter. While doing so, I encountered the following error: "emit was called after an event handler completed normally.". I was able to fix the error, but do not understand why it occurred in the first run.

First of all, the erroneous code here:

```
void _mapEventToState(NumberTriviaEvent event, Emitter<NumberTriviaState> emit) **async** {
    if (event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumber) {
      final inputEither = inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);
      inputEither.fold(
        (l) => emit(const Error(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE)),
        (r) **async** {
          emit(Loading());
          final failureOrTrivia = await getConcreteNumberTrivia(Params(number: r));
          NumberTriviaState x = _eitherLoadedOrErrorState(failureOrTrivia);
          emit(x);
        },
      );
    } ...
  }
```

Here after the getConcreteNumberTrivia call it is said that the EventHandling is done (`emit.done == true`). At `emit(x)` the mentioned error occurs.
And now the working code:

```
void _mapEventToState(NumberTriviaEvent event, Emitter<NumberTriviaState> emit) **async** {
    emit(Loading());
    if (event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumber) {
      int right = -1;

      final inputEither = inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);
      inputEither.fold(
            (l) => emit(const Error(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE)),
            (r) => right = r,
      );
      
      if(state is Error) {
        return;
      }

      final failureOrTrivia = await getConcreteNumberTrivia(Params(number: right));
      emit(_eitherLoadedOrErrorState(failureOrTrivia));
    } else if(event is GetTriviaForRandomNumber) {
      final failureOrTrivia = await getRandomNumberTrivia(NoParams());
      emit(_eitherLoadedOrErrorState(failureOrTrivia));
    }
}
```

I can actually only imagine that it is not possible to use async twice while handling events?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @pskink yeah, because I have to wait for the getConcreteNumberTrivia() result. Sorry, but I'm pretty new at the field of flutter. What do you mean with the for loop? Iterate over the either object? Thanks for your answer!